# Calling OpenGL Extensions from Python

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am using PyOpenGL 3 on Ubuntu Natty.

I want to use the [`glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xml) function.

I can see it listed in my glxinfo output, so I know my card has it.

However, I cannot find how to actually invoke it.  When I `import OpenGL.GL` I get a `NameError` if I try to use it.  (As distinct from it being `None`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to import the function through its extension name:

```
>>> from OpenGL.GL.ARB.draw_elements_base_vertex import *
>>> glDrawElementsBaseVertex
<OpenGL.platform.baseplatform.glDrawElementsBaseVertex object at 0x031D7B30>
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL extensions must be provided by the binding itself, PyOpenGL has no support for "chain loading" new extensions; while it was possible to implement such, it's just not worth the effort.

Maybe you just accessed the extension not properly. The PyOpenGL documentation explains, that there are several ways to do this

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/opengl_diffs.html

> Extensions and Conditional
>   Functionality PyOpenGL has support for
>   most OpenGL extensions.  Extensions
>   are available as "normal" function
>   pointers by importing the constructed
>   package name for the extension, for
>   instance:
>
> ```
> from OpenGL.GL.ARB.vertex_buffer_object import * buffer = glGenBuffersARB(1)
> ```
>
> there is no need to call
>   initialization functions or the like
>   for the extension module.  You can, if
>   you like, call the "init" function for
>   the extension to retrieve a boolean
>   indicating whether the local machine
>   supports a given extension, like so:
>
> ```
> if glInitVertexBufferObjectARB():     
>      ...
> ```
>
> However, it is normally clearer to
>   test for the boolean truth of the
>   entry points you wish to use:
>
> ```
> if (glGenBuffersARB): 
>     buffers = glGenBuffersARB( 1 )
> ```
>
> There are often a
>   number of entry points which implement
>   the same API, for which you would like
>   to use whichever implementation is
>   available (likely with some preference
>   in order).  The OpenGL.extensions
>   module provides an easy mechanism to
>   support this:
>
> ```
> from OpenGL.extensions import alternate
> glCreateProgram = alternate( 'glCreateProgram', glCreateProgram, glCreateProgramObjectARB)
> glCreateProgram = alternate( glCreateProgram, glCreateProgramObjectARB)
> ```
>
> If the first
>   element is a string it will be used as
>   the name of the alternate object,
>   otherwise the name is taken from the
>   first argument.